# Using AWS Ruby SDK, how can one get the current user's details?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

As can be seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197784/how-can-i-deduce-the-aws-account-id-from-available-basicawscredentials), the Java SDK has a [method to retrieve the current user based on the request's credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/AmazonIdentityManagement.html#getUser%28%29). Is there a way to do something similar using the Ruby SDK?

I've tried `AWS::IAM.new(creds).access_keys[creds[:access_key_id]]`, but that returns a simple object that answers `nil` to `user` or `user_name`, and my user doesn't have the `iam:ListUsers` permission so I can't enumerate the users collection.

Basically I need that information because I want to generate a self-approving policy to be attached to some new resources, and I need to fetch the ARN that my configured access key is associated with. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current user using the client class. If you are using version 1 of the AWS SDK for Ruby, the `aws-sdk` gem:

`iam = AWS::IAM::Client.new
iam.get_user`

If you prefer to use the new version 2 AWS SDK for Ruby, just change the root namespace from `AWS` to `Aws`:

`iam = Aws::IAM::Client.new
iam.get_user`

Comment: Thanks, that did the work. Its important to note that get_user requires a specific permission `iam:GetUser`, which is not granted by default to some roles, such as instance profiles.