# Determining an AWS arn from a federated user's credentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-sts

How can you determine what federated user belongs to a set of credentials? I've seen some options for finding a regular user, but temporary credentials created by getting a federation token don't seem to work since they don't have GetUser privileges.

User credentials are created like this:

```
GetFederationTokenRequest getFederationTokenRequest = new GetFederationTokenRequest()
                                                        .withDurationSeconds(7200)
                                                        .withName(userEmail)
                                                        .withPolicy(userPolicy.toString());
GetFederationTokenResult federationTokenResult = stsClient.getFederationToken(getFederationTokenRequest);
Credentials sessionCredentials = federationTokenResult.getCredentials();
BasicSessionCredentials basicSessionCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
              sessionCredentials.getAccessKeyId(), 
              sessionCredentials.getSecretAccessKey(), 
              sessionCredentials.getSessionToken());
```

So essentially using the accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, and session token, can I find an arn or username? I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197784/how-can-i-deduce-the-aws-account-id-from-available-basicawscredentials), which allows me to get it from an error message, but I'd rather find a better option.