# How can i log the roles being used in my s3client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

WE normally inject our roles via system environment variables, currently we are having issues to detmerine which role is being assigned to the s3client

```
S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder()
                .region(Region.of(region))
                .build();
```

Is there anywhere i can log the roles that being used by the client?

```
implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:s3")
version "2.18.21"
```

Comment: Is this Java? Please tag the question with the programming language you are using, and also edit your question to include the specific version of the AWS SDK you are using.

Comment: yes java, @MarkB

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307552/how-to-get-aws-account-details-using-java-api-not-for-iam-user Try looking at all the answers there to see if any will work for you.

Comment: In this specific case, where you're using the default client, you could also create an instance of the default `StsClient` as described in the post that MarkB linked. In the general case, where you might configure clients independently, that won't work, and there's no way to do it (short of finding the credential provider, which is an internal implementation detail and likely to change).

Comment: But this seems like an X-Y request. What is the _actual_ problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @kdgregory it seems like the question is specifically about logging what role the AWS SDK is picking up *automatically*. That isn't an X-Y problem.

Comment: @MarkB - perhaps it's a lack of imagination on my part, but I can't conceive of a reason to care about the role of a client _unless I'm trying to diagnose some other problem_. :shrug:

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from another post:

Using the AWS v2.0 Java SDK, you can use `software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.StsClient#getCallerIdentity.`

First add a dependency to the sts module, eg in gradle:

```
implementation platform("software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.14.2")
implementation "software.amazon.awssdk:sts"
```

Then:

```
log.info("{}", StsClient.create().getCallerIdentity());
```

will return:

```
GetCallerIdentityResponse(UserId=AJAIVBQXMUAJAIVBQXMU, Account=298232720644, Arn=arn:aws:iam::298232720644:user/adrian)
```